# Is gcc wrongly evaluating std::declval in this concept definition?

Tags: c++, g++, c++-concepts, c++20

In this concept definition:

```
#include <utility>

template<class Func, class Ret, class... Args>
concept Invokable = requires(Func f) {
    { f(std::declval<Args>()...) } -> Ret;
};
```

when instantiated like this:

```
static_assert(Invokable<decltype([](int){}), void, int>);
```

gcc-9.0.1 (trunk) dumps (well, the Standard Library implementation to be precise):

> ```
> $ g++ -O2 -std=c++2a -fconcepts -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c tu1.cpp
> error: static assertion failed: declval() must not be used!
> 2204 |       static_assert(__declval_protector<_Tp>::__stop,
>      |                                               ^~~~~~
> ```

demo: https://godbolt.org/z/D0ygU4

**Is it wrong to reject this code?** If not, what did I do wrong? If yes, where should one report this bug?

---

### Notes

#### This is accepted

```
template<auto f, class... Args>
constexpr auto size_of_return_type = sizeof(f(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

when instantiated like so:

```
static_assert(sizeof(int) == size_of_return_type<[](int){ return 0; }, int>);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/gYGk8U

#### Latest C++2a draft states:

> [`[expr.prim.req]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req#2)
> A requires-expression is a prvalue of type bool whose value is described below. Expressions appearing within a requirement-body are unevaluated operands.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it wrong to reject this code?

Yes, concepts are never evaluated, as evidenced in the quote you're citing. This is [gcc bug 68781](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68781) and [gcc bug 82171](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82171).

Note that there's no reason to use `declval` within concepts. This is more straightforward:

```
template<class Func, class Ret, class... Args>
concept InvokableR = requires(Func&& f, Args&&... args) {
    { f(std::forward<Args>(args)...) } -> Ret;
};
```

`declval` exists because you need some expression of some type and you can't just write `T()` because that requires a default constructor. Concepts give you that ability as a first-class language feature. Still need the `forward` though.

Comment: Thank you for your remark about the need for `std::forward`.